# Как осуществить глобальный поиск чатов в телеграм на Python?

Tags: python, api, telethon, telegram

Мне нужно собрать список групп в телеграмм по ключевому слову, надо собрать около 4000 групп, поэтому я хотел сделать это на Python через telethon, но не смог понять как, подскажите как это можно сделать(можно на других библиотеках или через сам api телеграма)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В телеграмме есть функция поиска, вводите название канала и он находит все каналы по этому названию, я хочу тоже самое сделать через Python

Answer (score 0):

Для этих целей есть telethon. Вот пример как через него можно сделать поиск https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205917/11695435

Вот код

config.ini

```
[Telegram]
# no need for quotes

# you can get telegram development credentials in telegram API Development Tools
api_id = 1234
api_hash = 1234

# use full phone number including + and country code
phone = +4411111111111
username = session_user
```

do_search.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Tested with Telethon version 1.14.0

import configparser
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

# Reading Configs
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
# (1) Use your own values here
api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']

# (2) Create the client and connect
phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.start()
    # Ensure you're authorized
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        try:
            await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            await client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))

    search = 'linux'
    result = await client(functions.contacts.SearchRequest(
        q=search,
        limit=100
    ))
    print(result.stringify())

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Да, я знаю этот метод, но проблема в том, что он ищет только среди чатов на которые ты подписан, а мне нужно чтобы он искал глобально